# How can I retrieve the content of a Redis channel at the time of subscribe?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

When my web app subscribes to a Redis channel (mostly on Application_Start), it should automatically load the current channel content, but not wait for the next publish within this channel.

I couldn't find any way to achieve this - but as this "problem" appears to be so common and trivial I guess there must be an easy solution for this?

In the web app I'm using StackExchange.Redis (in case that's relevant). Who can help? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, there is no option to do this using Redis pub/sub functionality, Redis don't actually store messages which being published to the channel, so you can't retrieve them when you connect to channel.

Take a look at RabbitMQ with their persistent queues and message acknowledgements, which they have out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

As there's obviously no comfortable option available in Redis, I'm now publishing the channel message also as a regular key-value. So the clients take it from key-value store before subscribing to the channel.